# Получение доступа к объекту в приватном поле дружественного класса

Tags: c++

Есть класс, назовём его Firstclass. В нём, в приватном поле определён структурный тип следующего вида:

```
using struct StructName {
                          QString nameFild;
                          QString nameFild1;
                          qint32 nameFild2;
                          ...
    };
```

Далее, в приватном поле этого же класса `(Firstclass)` объявлен объект шаблонного класса `QList <StructName> nameObject;` К этому классу `(Firstclass)` есть дружественный класс `TestClass`. Проблема заключается в том, что бы из описанных сущностей собрать объект и получать к нему доступ из класса `TestClass`. Объект должен быть вида:

```
StructName TestObject;
TestObject.nameFild1 = valueFild1;
TestObject.nameFild2 = valueFild2;
nameObject.append(TestObject);
```

`TestClass` и `Firstclass` лежат в разных файлах. В классе `Firstclass` менять ничего нельзя. Единственное что я могу сделать, это объявить к нему дружественный класс `TestClass`. Я пишу Unit тесты для функций класса `Firstclass` и мне нужно через методы класса `TestClass` передавать данные в `Firstclass`. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

class Firstclass
{
    friend class Testclass;
public:
    Firstclass() = default;

private:
    struct StructName
    {
        std::string nameFild1;
    };
    std::list<StructName> objectName;
};

class Testclass
{
public:
    Testclass() = default;

    void doSomethingWithFirstclass(Firstclass& firstclass)
    {
        Firstclass::StructName TestObject;
        TestObject.nameFild1 = "name";
        firstclass.objectName.push_back(TestObject);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Firstclass firstclassObject;
    Testclass testclassObject;


    testclassObject.doSomethingWithFirstclass(firstclassObject);
}
```